# Task naming problem when exporting to cloud disk

Tags: google-earth-engine

I defined a new string as the task name when exporting to the cloud disk, but the final result was not what I expected. The output style is as shown below. How should I solve this? I tried to use print() and found that it is normal display,it print out something like "LC08_146034_20190106_LST"

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2');
var path = 146  
var row = 34;
var landsat_lst = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_PATH', path))
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('WRS_ROW', row))
  .filterDate('2019-01-01', '2020-01-01');
print(landsat_lst)
//B10 LST BAND
function exportImageCollection(imagecollection) { 
  var indexList = imagecollection.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.toList(), ["system:index"]) 
                        .get("list"); 
  indexList.evaluate(function(indexs) { 
    for (var i=0; i<indexs.length; i++) { 
      var image = imagecollection.filter(ee.Filter.eq("system:index", indexs[i])).first(); 
      var string_name = ee.String(indexs[i]).cat('_LST')
      print(string_name)
      Export.image.toDrive({ 
        image: image.select('ST_B10'),
        description: string_name, 
        fileNamePrefix: string_name, 
        scale: 30, 
        crs: "EPSG:4326", 
        maxPixels: 1e13 
      }); 
    } 
  }); 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to avoid `ee.String` while computing the name — or, well, you could, but you'd have to `evaluate()` it again and it's wasteful to call the Earth Engine service just to do a little concatenation. Do it in 'plain JavaScript' style instead; replace

```js
var string_name = ee.String(indexs[i]).cat('_LST')
```

with

```js
var string_name = indexs[i] + '_LST';
```

Comment: Thank you so much!